# How does Nike+ work?

Tags: rf, ipod

The Nike+iPod Sports Kit is a device which measures and records the distance and pace of a walk or run. The Nike+iPod consists of a small accelerometer[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nike+) attached to or embedded in a shoe, which communicates with either the Nike+ Sportband, a receiver plugged into an iPod Nano, or directly with a 2nd, 3rd, or 4th Generation iPod Touch, iPhone 3GS or iPhone 4. If using the iPod or the iPhone 3GS, iTunes software can be used to view the walk or run history. [Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nike+)

What type of RF communication is used between the device embedded in the shoe and the iPod? Could I create my own receiver and log data without an iPod?

Comment: http://hackaday.com/2011/04/19/eagerfeet-lets-you-scrape-your-nike-data-from-the-web/

Comment: Nike+ module teardown - http://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/41

Comment: We're all just supposed to know what you think "Nike+" means!?

Comment: The question body should stand on its own and not rely on the title for important information.  -1 for a poorly worded and lazily written question.

Comment: @Olin Being politer to new users might help encourage them in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sparkfun did a teardown of the Nike+ module [here](http://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/41).

The Nike+ shoe dongle uses a [nRF2402](http://www.nvlsi.no/index.cfm?obj=product&act=display&pro=78) RFIC and a PIC [16F688](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en010215).

The receiver uses a nRF2401A and a ASIC.

And yes, sparkfun sells a USB <-> Nike+ receiver [here](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/8245).

---

<sub>I've basically scraped all this info from Sparkfun. Thanks, Sparkfun!</sub>

Comment: How did I miss that on Sparkfun? Thanks for pointing it out.